# Outlook 64 bit using Redemption 64 bit from 32 bit application

Tags: delphi, outlook, 64-bit, 32-bit, outlook-redemption

I have a 32bit Delphi application which needs to use Redemption to talk with Outlook. For deployment on 64 bit machines with 64 bit Outlook installed, Redemption has a 64 bit version of its COM dll.

Redemption is registered properly and can be used from a test program made in C#, but when trying to access Redemption from the 32 bit Delphi app i get an error "Class not registered". This is probably due to it being registered in the 64 branch of the registry and Delphi not looking there, but I'd like to know if there's any way to get this working possible with a nice workaround or something ?

The Delphi application is enormous and being rewritten in C# but this will take a while. Until then it will have to work in the 32 bit Delphi app.

Comment: FWIW, as of 2011 (or late 2010?), there is a 64-bit build of Redemption available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 32-bit application cannot use a 64-bit COM DLL.

Can 64-bit Outlook use 32-bit Redemption?  If not, you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Make a 64 bit gateway helper application in C# or Lazarus/FreePascal, that receives input via TCP from your existing Delphi 32 bit application, and translates and forwards it's output to 64 bit Redemption COM. That way you don't have to rewrite the whole application.